# OpenMP parallel function calls

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have some Fortran code which has been written for scientific purposes. There are two conditional function calls which are tested and run sequentially. The calls to these functions I would like to parallelise as they do not relate to each other. However, I am unsure about the best way to do it.

A sample of the code I have is as follows:

```
...

if ( flag1 ) then
  stat1 = func1( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % b )
  if ( stat1 .gt. 0 ) then
    call die_error("error message")
    status = 1
    return
  end if
end if

if ( flag2 ) then
  stat2 = func2( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % c )
  if ( stat2 .gt. 0 ) then
    call die_error("error message 2")
    status = 1
    return
  end if
end if

...
```

The flags `flag1` and `flag2` are user defined, one of them may be true or both may be true or both may be false which is why they are tested independently.

The function arguments `tm` and `dt` are integer and double precision variables respectively but they are not altered by `func1` or `func2`.

The custom data type `struct` contains three double precision arrays: `a`, `b` and `c`. The array `struct % a` is not altered by `func1` or `func2`. However, `struct % b` **is** altered by `func1` and `struct % c` **is** altered by `func2`.

In the particular case when `flag1` and `flag2` are both true, then `func1` and `func2` may be called in parallel. However, I am unsure of the following:

1. how to correctly deal with the custom data type; do I need locks for example?
2. how to correctly deal with `struct % a` as it isn't altered by the code; `firstprivate(struct % a)` for example?
3. how to correctly implement the conditions as I only wish to parallelise if `flag1` and `flag2` are both true?

My attempt is as follows:

```
...

!$omp parallel num_threads(2) firstprivate(tm, dt, struct % a) if(flag1 .and. flag2)
  !$omp master
    !$omp task lastprivate(stat1)
      stat1 = func1( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % b )
    !$omp end task

    !$omp task lastprivate(stat2)
      stat2 = func2( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % c )
    !$omp end task

    !$omp taskwait

    if ( (stat1 .gt. 0) .or. (stat2 .gt. 0) ) then
      call die_error("error message")
      status = 1
      return
    end if
  !$omp end master
!$omp end parallel

if ( flag1 .and. .not.flag2 ) then
  stat1 = func1( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % b )
  if ( stat1 .gt. 0 ) then
    call die_error("error message")
    status = 1
    return
  end if
end if

if ( flag2 .and. .not.flag1 ) then
  stat2 = func2( tm, dt, struct % a, struct % c )
  if ( stat2 .gt. 0 ) then
    call die_error("error message 2")
    status = 1
    return
  end if
end if

...
```

A few further questions I have from above are:

4. Is the `!$omp master` directive necessary?
5. Should `!$omp sections` directive be used instead of `!$omp task`?
6. Is my return from the `!$omp parallel` directive safe if either `func1` or `func2` fail?